# MacBook Pro gets hung up and rebooted when I disconnect the 4K LG UltraFine monitor (Thunderbolt 3)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt

MacBook Pro 15" 2017 gets hung up when I disconnect the 4K LG UltraFine monitor. Then it reboots after some seconds. This occurred 2 times. The monitor connects by Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C). macOS 11.3.1.

I tried to find a cause in the Console app (system.log) at the time of the disconnection, but there are too many events at the time and I can not find the event when the system is hung.

How to diagnose what is a problem (hardware or software)? And how to fix it?

Comment: What have you done so far? Are you sure its a full reboot, not just a respring (i.e. it shows the login window very quickly without the Apple boot logo)? My test strategy would be to rule out hardware and then software. Some ideas: test all the different ports, test the monitor with another computer, test the MBP with another monitor, quit all programs (is DisplayLink installed?), reset SMC and NVRAM/PRAM. You might also want to try and boot into diagnose mode and safe mode. Also, 17" with TB 3 doesnt exist, I guess its a typo and you mean 16"?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In both cases it was the full reboot, I saw the Apple boot logo, listened to the boot sound, OS asks me to start new login and OS said something like “your computer was rebooted, do you want to send a crash report?” 
I mean 2017, so it is MBP 15” 2017. I do not know what DisplayLink is, I googled it, and I don’t use any kind of DL product. I have only one computer with TB3 and only one monitor with TB3. I will try to reset SMC and NVRAM/PRAM if this behavior will be repeated. Meanwhile, for now, I cannot reproduce this case to make sure that resetting has helped.